# find and replace in json file using jq filter

Tags: json, shell, jq, jsonparser

I've below json file `env.json` and I want to search for `"[\"res\",\"q3\"]"` and replace it with a variable `var1` value `"[\"res\"]"`

```
{
  "idsb": "marqd",
  "data": {
    "name": "bcon-dv-alert"
  },
  "ingress": {
    "args": {
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "spt",
          "value": "cld"
        },
        {
          "name": "scv",
          "value": "sdv"
        },
        {
          "name": "scr",
          "value": "ord"
        }
        {
          "name": "srm",
          "value": "[\"res\",\"q3\"]"
        },
        {
          "name": "tgo",
          "value": "pbc"
        }
      ]
    },
    "wfr": {
      "name": "t-r-e"
    },
    "snm": "as-r"
  }
}
```

I tried the below way but it's not working

`var1="[\"res\"]"`

`jq '.ingress.args.params[] | select(.name=="srm").value |= ["'${var1}'"]' env.json`

where am making mistake? what's the right way to do it?

The final result will be

```
{
  "idsb": "marqd",
  "data": {
    "name": "bcon-dv-alert"
  },
  "ingress": {
    "args": {
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "spt",
          "value": "cld"
        },
        {
          "name": "scv",
          "value": "sdv"
        },
        {
          "name": "scr",
          "value": "ord"
        }
        {
          "name": "srm",
          "value": "[\"res\"]"
        },
        {
          "name": "tgo",
          "value": "pbc"
        }
      ]
    },
    "wfr": {
      "name": "t-r-e"
    },
    "snm": "as-r"
  }
}
```

Comment: Surround the LHS of the assignment with parantheses (and use `--arg` for external data): `jq --arg v "$var1" '(.ingress.args.params[] | select(.name=="srm").value) = $v' env.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to update `ingress`, and not return only the result of the loops, use:

```
.ingress.args.params |= map(select(.name=="srm").value |= "new-value")
```

#### [Try it online](https://jqplay.org/s/2aPijgp8gra)